# where is underscore _.isString function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I cannot find where/how the _.isString method is implemented in underscore.js. I am simply curious to see how it is implemented, yet it is a mystery to me.

I know there are much better ways to go about checking if an object is a string, which is not my wuestion, I am simply curious as to how the _.isString() method works when it is not in the source.

For reference here is the underscore source: http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a ctrl+f for "isString" it's about 80% of the way down:

```
// Add some isType methods: isArguments, isFunction, isString, isNumber, isDate, isRegExp, isError.
_.each(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp', 'Error'], function(name) {
  _['is' + name] = function(obj) {
    return toString.call(obj) === '[object ' + name + ']';
  };
});
```

`_.isString` expands to:

```
_.isString = function(obj) {
  return toString.call(obj) === '[object String]' 
}
```

Comment: It's easy to reference the source code directly ~ https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1319

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that they generate functions like this. I was thinking there was wizardry going on for a while

Comment: I'm glad they put it in the comments as I've run across this a few times. :) too much magic can lead to confusion at the cost of saving bytes.